# Magnifying glass effect on screenshots

Tags: screenshot

I use Snagit to capture screenshots on my PC and saw the picture below that has a magnifying glass effect on it. I tried to recreate it on Snagit but the magnify options are pretty basic and I don't like the output.

[image]

How can I achieve this rather easily without too much complex photo editing? It would be counter productive for me to spend more than 5 minutes editing each screenshot I take, so I am looking for the best practice here.

Comment: Seeing that you don't want to edit the photos yourself this sounds like you're looking for a better Screenshot Application. As such I'm voting to close this to be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: You basically have to take 2 screenshots - one normal and 1 enlarged. Then you can configure a master document to mask out the enlargement and create the effect. However, if you're unwilling to do anything more than take a screen shot - I don't think there's a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Seems that this technique described in the video works in Snagit http://www.screencast.com/t/D8bc96JVRTHy
If you know any simpler method to do this, please do tell.

Comment: How long does it take in SnagIt? You can do that in no time in Photoshop if you have access to that app?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac there is an application that will do this very easily. It is called [Napkin](http://aged-and-distilled.com/). It makes Snagit's magnify tool look awful.